# How to build an android app with external libraries using ant?

Tags: android, ant

I have an existing project that builds fine using my IDE.  I'd like to use the "[android update](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/developing/other-ide.html#UpdatingAProject)" command to generate an ant buildfile for this project.

The buildfile is generated fine, but the build fails because it's not building with some jarfiles I have in my libs directory.

I'd like to figure out the proper way to tell ant to build with some external jar files in my libs directory.  How should I do this?  Is it a property in build.properties?  Do I need to modify build.xml somehow?  Or is there a different solution entirely?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> but the build fails because it's not
>   building with some jarfiles I have in
>   my libs directory.

And your error message is...what? I suspect you may be misinterpreting the error message.

> I'd like to figure out the proper way
>   to tell ant to build with some
>   external jar files in my libs
>   directory. How should I do this?

Just put them in `libs/`, as Ant will add everything in there to your build path. See [this project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Java/AndShell/), and [this project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/16-JAR/), and [this project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/TwitterWidget/) for examples.

Comment: Ah, the problem is that one of my dependencies is a project dependency rather than a jar dependency.  I'll fix that.

Comment: Thanks commonsware.  If you'd like to take a stab at a follow-up, I have another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466437/how-to-build-an-android-test-app-with-a-dependency-on-another-app-using-ant

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one. I am not a fan of the Android test framework, so I don't know the answer there. Sorry!

Comment: @emmby How you fixed that issues? (" the problem is that one of my dependencies is a project dependency rather than a jar dependency")

Answer (score 14):

I spent some time trying to get the Facebook API to work with ant.  The trick for me was to add this to my default.properties files.

```
android.library.reference.1=../Facebook
```

Where ../Facebook contains AndroidManifest.xml, etc.  The real key being the relative path.  Don't use an absolute path because Ant seems to treat your project directory as the root.

This should hold true for other library projects that you are including from source code.

Comment: Take a look at TicTacToeLib&TicTacToeMain in sdk examples. And read README.txt files.

Comment: This was exactly the answer I needed, brief and up to the point.

Comment: Why the .1 in that definition?

Answer (score 8):

I was dealing with similar issue. I'm building Android project on Jenkins using standard Ant build.xml (generated by Android SDK). I also have reference to another Java project with some shared domain classes. In Eclipse there is no problem with it. The domain project is a project reference. However on Jenkins this domain.jar is built by Maven and it was not accessible by Android project.

I have finally solved it by adding this at the end of build.xml:

```
<target name="-pre-build">
  <copy todir="${jar.libs.dir}">
    <fileset 
      dir="../path-to-another-project/target" 
      includes="*.jar" />
  </copy>
</target>
```

This copies all jars from the target directory of another project into "libs" directory of my Android project. The -pre-build Ant target is automatically called before Android compilation starts.

Comment: Instead of changing build.xml, you should add a custom_rules.xml to the same directory as build.xml.  Put the -pre-build target in there and build.xml will automatically import it.  custom_rules.xml can contain all your pre and post build operations

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mark, however, if you're planning to modify your build script further - than you need to make it custom. Bring tasks from android/platforms/android-PLATFORMVERSION/templates/android_rules.xml to your build.xml and modify whatever you want to modify. Including location for external libs.