# Which is the build tool we can use with Robotium for Android Automation

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

I am having Automation Scripts ready for my android application, Now i want to integrates with any build tool, which can run my scripts in daily basis.Please let me know is there any build tool we can use.

Answer (score 0):

Ant is a good option. Previously posted by someone on stackoverflow. See this link: [Can't build and run an android test project created using "ant create test-project" when tested project has jars in libs directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472059/cant-build-and-run-an-android-test-project-created-using-ant-create-test-proje)