# Android unit test using ant with library project R18

Tags: android, unit-testing, ant

I am having the same issues as in This question: [Android unit test using ant with library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595006/android-unit-test-using-ant-with-library-project)

I tried both methods that was suggested in the question, but on the r18 release of the android tools, I am getting:

```
NTServicesTest/build.xml:110: Reference jar.libs.ref not found.
```

I am not sure if it's me who have failed at following the recipe for the workaround for the answers to the original question, or if something has changed in r18 of the android tools.

my folder setup is on proj folder that contains..:

NTServices , 
NTServicesTest ,
NTServicesTestApp

For the workaround of @Snicolas
I modified my NTServicesTest/project.properties to look like this:

```
# Project target.
target=android-15
tested.android.library.reference.1=../NTServices
```

And my NTServicesTest/build.xml looks like this : (from right under the version tag )

```
 <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />


    <!-- override "compile" target in platform android_rules.xml to include tested app's external libraries -->
 <!-- Compiles this project's .java files into .class files. -->
<target name="-compile" depends="-build-setup, -pre-build, -code-gen, -pre-compile">
<do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">
    <!-- If android rules are used for a test project, its classpath should include
         tested project's location -->
    <condition property="extensible.classpath"
            value="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/bin/classes"
            else=".">
        <isset property="tested.project.absolute.dir" />
    </condition>
    <condition property="extensible.libs.classpath"
            value="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/${jar.libs.dir}"
            else="${jar.libs.dir}">
        <isset property="tested.project.absolute.dir" />
    </condition>
    <echo message="jar libs dir : ${tested.project.target.project.libraries.jars}"/>
    <javac encoding="${java.encoding}"
            source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"
            debug="true" extdirs="" includeantruntime="false"
            destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
            bootclasspathref="android.target.classpath"
            verbose="${verbose}"
            classpath="${extensible.classpath}"
            classpathref="jar.libs.ref">
        <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
        <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />
        <classpath>
            <!-- steff: we changed one line here !-->
            <fileset dir="${tested.android.library.reference.1}/bin/" includes="*.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${extensible.libs.classpath}" includes="*.jar" />
        </classpath>
        <compilerarg line="${java.compilerargs}" />
    </javac>
           <!-- if the project is instrumented, intrument the classes -->
                    <if condition="${build.is.instrumented}">
                        <then>
                            <echo>Instrumenting classes from ${out.absolute.dir}/classes...</echo>
                            <!-- It only instruments class files, not any external libs -->
                            <emma enabled="true">
                                <instr verbosity="${verbosity}"
                                       mode="overwrite"
                                       instrpath="${out.absolute.dir}/classes"
                                       outdir="${out.absolute.dir}/classes">
                                </instr>
                                <!-- TODO: exclusion filters on R*.class and allowing custom exclusion from
                                     user defined file -->
                            </emma>
                        </then>
                    </if>           
</do-only-if-manifest-hasCode>
</target>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just rename classpathref="jar.libs.ref" to classpathref="project.libraries.jars".

Answer (score 2):

yes it worked. in R18 this propertyes changet to project.libraries.jars but in owerrided task we did'nt change this value