# Eclipse build okay but ant build throws resourcenotfoundexception in Using Facebook SDK external library

Tags: android, facebook, ant

Been SO-ing and Google-ing this and have tried several solutions but still came up short:

I have the following:

mainproject           ---> call this A

Facebook SDK(library) ---> call this B

Done "android update" in both and my project.properties for

A:

```
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:8
android.library=false
android.library.reference.1=../../facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1/facebook
```

B:

```
android.library=true
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:8
```

Eclipse builds okay and all functionalities in Facebook run okay.

When I compile it via ant it also compiles good.  However when I launch the compiled apk (done via ant) in emulator or device I get a crash to wit:
ResourceNotFoundException
and this is the first xml resource that is being called (the splash screen xml) which has been doing okay with previous build (pre-Facebook integration).

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

Would appreciate receiving any answers/links from anyone experiencing the same.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, you have to copy all your jars into A/libs, see this other Stack Overflow answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905963/2552687